# Make layout size depend on image size in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently writing an android app with **Android Studio**. In order to fit most screen sizes I decided to use LinearLayouts inside ConstraintLayout.
I have the following code for xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
tools:context=".Kadr1Activity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrKadr1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lol" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrNext"
            android:onClick="nextClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_back" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrNext"
            android:onClick="nextClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_next" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want ImageButtons height depend on the height of the ImageView. I tried using RelativeLayout, however, I cannot get how to implement dependencies not on whole screen size, but only on ImageView size.

So, how can I adjust height of my horizontal LinearLayout (with buttons) to be 4 times smaller (for example) than ImageView height?

Would be grateful for any possible advice.

Comment: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html -> "layout weight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marcin Orlowski, I got it:

should set ImageView height to "0dp", horizontal LinearLayout height to "0dp", then set ImageView weight to "4" and LinearLayout weight to "1".

It works properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
tools:context=".Kadr1Activity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrKadr1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lol" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrNext"
            android:onClick="nextClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_back" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescrNext"
            android:onClick="nextClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_next" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```